# Solving an IVP using Laplace

Tags: laplace-transform

Solve the IVP:

$x''(t) + x(t) + sin^2t = 0$  subject to $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 0$ using Laplace.

I have found out that $L[sin^2t](s)$ is $\frac{1} {2s}- \frac1 2(\frac{s}{s^2+4})$ but I need a guide through in solving the actual equation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First, what is the formula for the Laplace Transform of the nth derivative of $x(t)$ ? Then, solve for $\mathcal{L} (x(t))$ and then take the inverse laplace transform of both sides to get $x(t)$.  You might have to use a table for it.

Comment: $L[f'](s) = sL[f](s) − f(0).$ @VivekKaushik

Comment: What about for $\mathcal{L} (x''(t))$ ?

Comment: For example $L[x''(t)]= s^2X(s)$ and $L[x'(t)]=sX(s)$ @VivekKaushik

Comment: and $-f'(0)$ and $-f(0)$ added to them respectively @VivekKaushik

Comment: So what is $\mathcal{L}( x(t) )$ given all the data that you have ? You need solve for that given your equation. Is it clear what I am asking ?

Comment: $L[x(t)]= X(s)-f(0)$ @VivekKaushik

Comment: I mean in your differential equation $x''(t) +x(t) + \sin^2(t) =0,$ when you take the Laplace transform of both sides, how would you solve for $\mathcal{L} (x(t))$ ? When you solve a differential equation like this one, you need to solve for $\mathcal{L}(x(t))$  and then take the inverse laplace transform of both sides to get  $x(t).$

Comment: So would you get $L[x''(t)] + L[x(t)] +L[sin^2t]=L[0](s)$ which equals $s^2X(s) +X(s)+\frac{1}{2s}-\frac1 2(\frac{s}{s^2+4})=0$ @VivekKaushik

Comment: So solve for $X(s)$ and then take the inverse Laplace transform of both sides to get $x(t).$ I think you would need a table for finding the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: could you verify if my previous step is correct? @VivekKaushik

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: solving for $X(s)$, would you sub out $X(s)$ to get $X(s)(s^2+1)$? but if i do that, is there anyway i could simplify the rest of the equation? @VivekKaushik

Comment: That's part of it. And then you divide both sides of the equation by $s^2+1$ and rearrange terms to get $X(s).$

Comment: I get $\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{s}{(s^2+4)}-\frac{1}{2s}}{(s^2+1)}$ i dont really know how to simplify this. Any tips? @VivekKaushik

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, we take the Laplace transform of both sides of the Differential Equation. Doing this gives

$$s^2 \mathcal{L}(x(t)) + \mathcal{L}(x(t))+\mathcal{L}(\sin^2(t))=0,$$

which means

$$s^2 \mathcal{L}(x(t)) + \mathcal{L}(x(t))=-\mathcal{L}(\sin^2(t)).$$

We have $$-\mathcal{L}(\sin^2(t))= -\frac{1}{2s} + \frac{s}{2(s^2+4)}.$$

so

$$\mathcal{L} (x(t))= \frac{1}{s^2+1} \left ( -\frac{1}{2s} + \frac{s}{2(s^2+4)} \right )=\frac{2s}{3(s^2+1)} -\frac{s}{6(s^2+4)} -\frac{1}{2s}$$ by partial fractions.  Use tables to find out what the inverse Laplace Transform of the right hand side is. Does this guide you in the right direction ?

Comment: Have you edited your answer??

Comment: I copied what Wolfram Alpha computed. This is the correct answer, for sure.    You will need partial fractions to show it.

Comment: Are you saying I need to use partial fractions on your answer or you used partial fractions to get your answer??

Comment: Partial fractions to get that answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you know how to finish the problem ?

Comment: Ive used the inverse table, do you get $x(t)=\frac2 3cos(t)-\frac1 6cos(2t)-\frac1 2$

Comment: Yes I did get that answer.

Comment: Ok, thank for the help

Comment: No problem. I am sorry if I was not clear at times. I didn't mean to do that.